# SQL query does not behave similarly in MSSQL and in H2

Tags: sql-server, spring, h2, r2dbc

I have the following SQL request that fetches a user's documents and filters them with a LIKE :

```sql
SELECT d.* FROM document d
WHERE d.owner = :uuid
AND UPPER(CONCAT(d.name, '.', d.extension)) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :documentName, '%'))
ORDER BY d.id OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :limit ROWS ONLY
```

When I execute this request directly on my MSSQL database, it works perfectly and it returns the expected documents.

When I put this request in my R2DBC repository like this :

```java
@Repository
interface DocumentRepository extends R2dbcRepository<DocumentEntity, Long> {
    @Query(
        "SELECT d.* FROM document d " +
        "WHERE d.owner = :uuid " +
        "AND UPPER(CONCAT(d.name, '.', d.extension)) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :documentName, '%')) " +
        "ORDER BY d.id OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :limit ROWS ONLY"
    )
    Flux<DocumentEntity> findAllByOwner(UUID uuid, String documentName, long offset, long limit);
}
```

It also works well when I'm hitting the MSSQL database in my local environment.

However, when I'm running integration tests on my app, I'm actually using an H2 database instead of an MSSQL database container, and in this case, the query does not work and always returns an empty flux, even when I use the same argument values and on the same database.

Any idea why the query does not behave similarly in my MSSQL container and in my H2 database ?

I'm using the following setup :

- MSSQL 2019 CU10 15.0.4123.1 on an Ubuntu 20.04 docker container in my local environment

Maven dependencies :

- H2 : com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:test
- R2DBC H2 : io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2:jar:0.8.4.RELEASE:test
- R2DBC MSSQL : io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql:jar:0.8.5.RELEASE:compile

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the query, it should work on both SQL dialects, but why not just use [testcontainers.org](https://testcontainers.org) for integration testing with SQL Server? You'll save yourself a lot of hassle

Comment: Yes that's what I was planning on doing anyway, I'll try that and update the post